# Upload A File from URL to AnonFiles [Remote Upload]

Tags: python, bash, powershell, curl, file-upload

I have bunch of Archived Assets from a project and i want to store it to AnonFiles via curl. The Assets is stored in my Google Drive and i want to remote upload the files direct link to AnonFiles, it's kinda moving the cloud-project to another file-cloud. Here's the AnonFiles API Docs:
https://anonfiles.com/docs/api
https://github.com/nstrydom2/anonfile-api

I usually try to download the Assets first to my local storage and then upload it to AnonFiles but it's not efficient as it requires 2-step. Here's some snippet i usually use:

```
class DownloadProgressBar(tqdm):
    def update_to(self, b=1, bsize=1, tsize=None):
        if tsize is not None:
            self.total = tsize
        self.update(b * bsize - self.n)
def downLoader(url, output_path):
    with DownloadProgressBar(unit='B', unit_scale=True,
                             miniters=1, desc=url.split('/')[-1]) as t:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename=output_path, reporthook=t.update_to)
downLoader('https://drive.google.direct.link/blabla','proj')
```

and then upload the file using powershell / bash:

```
curl.exe -F "file=@proj" https://api.anonfiles.com/upload?token=<key>
```

Is there a way to shorten the process without having the files to be downloaded onto my Local Storage? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: If you want to upload files from Google Drive to another API without acting as middle man, your best bet is probably a Google Apps script

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I kinda want the solution as Universal; meaning it works for any direct-link because; i may have to move files from my Cloudflare Workers to AnonFiles.

Comment: The only option I can think of would be to ditch `curl` completely, and use `urllib` for the upload too - implement a custom request handler that reads the response from google drive and immediately push the data upstream to anonfiles

Comment: Yeah, i'm thinking to use a different package, i've change the title for wider variety.